# Eating a Yom Tov meal on Yom Kippur

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, fast-days, meat, kiddush

If someone must eat on Yom Kippur, do they make kiddush on wine and have two challah rolls, plus meat and fish like he would on any other Yom Tov?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5784/kiddush-on-yom-kippur But note that even the opinions that you do make Kiddush seem to mean on bread if you have to eat bread in sufficient quantity. No one says to drink wine unnecessarily just for the purpose of Kiddush.

Comment: @Yishai If you have to drink anyway (more likely than you have to eat) then why not say Kiddush on it?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Kiddush is only BeMakom Seuda. If you had to drink wine (say in a place where water wasn't potable or something), then maybe (if you had to drink enough of it, or if you had to eat bread as well).

Comment: @Yishai You could drink two reviyot (or really, a male lugmav + a reviit). Why "in a place where water wasn't potable"? If you have to drink, might as well get some calories, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA, Alcohol is dehydrating, and I assume the goal is to get hydrated with the least amount of liquid as possible. If you are thinking of grape juice, it may not make a Makom Seuda with a reviit (at least that is what my LOR said, but I don't know the source).

Comment: @DavidFeigen CYLOR, but if you have to eat on a fast, you're supposed to eat in shiurim, which by definition are not enough to fulfill conditions of a meal.

Comment: @DavidFeigen Don't forget to CYLOR and eat more than a shiur if you need to for your life.

Answer (score 6):

A person who eats on Yom Kipour does not *make kiddush and have two challah rolls, plus meat and fish just as any other yom tov*.

The reason being that they should be eating as little as possible - just enough to keep alive & healthy.

However, they do say יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא if they ate enough bread - as well as רְצֵה if it's also Shabbat.

*Enough bread*: 27 gram according to the Yalkut Yosef.

---

Sources:

- Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim, 618:10 - סימן תריח - דין חולה ביום הכפורים and see the  באר היטב regarding Kiddush.

  - חוֹלֶה שֶׁאָכַל בְּיוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים וְנִתְיַשֵּׁב דַּעְתּוֹ בָּעִנְיָן שֶׁיָּכוֹל לְבָרֵךְ, צָרִיךְ לְהַזְכִּיר שֶׁל יוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים בְּבִרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן, שֶׁאוֹמֵר: (ח) יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא, בְּבוֹנֵה יְרוּשָׁלַיִם. ‏
  - באר היטב  (ח) יעלה ויבא. ואם חל בשבת אומר רצה. כנה''ג. וט''ז כתב שלא להזכיר יעלה ויבא ע''ש והמ''א העלה דאין להקל. ועכ''פ א''צ לקדש דיש לחוש לברכה לבטלה ע''ש: ‏
- Aruch Hashulchan ibid 618:17 who wonders why the custom is for them to say יַעֲלֶה וְיָבֹא.

  - חולה שאכל ביום הכיפורים, ונתיישב דעתו בענין שיכול לברך – צריך להזכיר של יום הכיפורים בברכת המזון. והיינו שיאמר ''יעלה ויבא'' כמו בתפילה, ויאמרנה ב''בונה ירושלים'' כמו בכל יום טוב. ואם חל בשבת אומר ''רצה והחליצנו''. 
    וגדולי האחרונים מפקפקים הרבה בדין זה, שהרי לא היום גורם האכילה, אלא מחלתו גרמה לו, ולמה יזכור יום הכיפורים בברכת המזון? (ט''ז, ומגן אברהם סעיף קטן י) ולא ידעתי איך החולים נוהגים בזה. מיהו קידוש וודאי אינו צריך (שם). ‏
- Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 133:18 - סימן קלג - הלכות יום הכפורים

  - מְבָרֵךְ לִפְנֵיהֶם וּלְאַחֲרֵיהֶם, אֲבָל קִדּוּשׁ לֹא יַעֲשֶׂה, וּבְבִּרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן אוֹמֵר יַעֲלֶה וְיָבוֹא. וְאִם חָל בַּשַׁבָּת, אוֹמֵר גַּם רְצֵה. וְאִם שָׁכַח, אֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לַחֲזוֹר וּלְבָרֵךְ, שֶׁאֵין חִיוּב הַיּוֹם לֶאֱכוֹל פַּת .‏

Comment: But what if they do have to eat so much that they can eat meat etc.? Is there still an idea of Kavod Yom Tov? What does Lechem Mishneh have to do with volume eaten? Note most (all?) Ashkenazi authorities reject a measurement in grams.

Comment: i dont think maadanim are allowed. The bigger question is if its shabbos, is there an inyan then because oneg shabbos is a m"kor oraisa