# If someone has broken their fast on Yom Kippur is anything extra added to birchas hamazon?

Tags: food, fast-days, yom-kippur, bentching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Benching on yom kipper](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/909/benching-on-yom-kipper)

I have heard that if one breaks his fast on Yom Kippur he should add into his birchas hamazon the section of "Yaaleh V'yavo". Is this true or do you add in something else (for example a special "Harachaman") or both?